# ntbackup asks for a free media LTO-1, but shouldn't

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, ntbackup, lto

I'm facing this problem: on Windows 2003 server STD, I can't safely perform unattended data backup on tape (HP LTO-1 drive) because it asks for a free media tape after 90GB of data written. The hardware compression is enabled, so I expect to back-up a minimum of 100GB of data. But the backup stops before the nominal tape capacity, while some week ago I was able to backup 148GB of data. For example, last wednesday:

> Backup started on 14/03/2012 at 23.07.
>   The requested media failed to mount. The operation was aborted.
>   The operation was ended.
>   Backup completed on 15/03/2012 at 3.59.
>   Directories: 12393
>   Files: 182764
>   Bytes: 96.219.704.680
>   Time:  4 hours,  51 minutes, and  44 seconds

We have 130 tapes, the older is from 2005, the newest is from nov. 2011. Each tape written it's stowed in a cabinet for 14 months, after this period is rewritten (we make 2 full backups a week).

In Event Viewer there is only error 8019:

> Event Type:    Error
>   Event Source:  NTBackup
>   Event Category:    None
>   Event ID:  8019
>   Date:      15/03/2012
>   Time:      3.59.01
>   User:      N/A
>   Computer:  W3KSRV01
>   Description:
>   End Operation: Warnings or errors were encountered. 
>   Consult the backup report for more details.

Where should I investigate? This afternoon I have to patch the server (monthly fix) and of course reboot...

Update: from "Computer Management" I can't free a tape (the option is grayed). But from ntbackup I can free it. I think that something hanged in the system...

Update2: after the reboot, the nightly backup went OK: 98GB+System State. Let's wait some time to see if the problem is gone away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- If the media is old, maybe the drive has to skip some sectors because it can't reliable read the data after the write (LTO always does a verify-after-write). Try a new tape and see if you can store more data on it.
- This shouldn't be a problem if you backup your OS, but if you backup only pre-compressed files (archives, JPGs, MP3 etc)., it *might* be that activating hardware compression actually increases the backup size.

Comment: At least one media was "new", i.e. used for the second time  
The type of data is a mix of DTP files (pdf, ai, indd, jpg, tiff, eps) and aother files, from the beginning.  We never had a trouble until the total size was under 110GB.